# Algorithm to find nth working day

Tags: algorithm

I have deviced a procedure to find nth working day without using loops.

Please bring around your suggesstions over this -

Algorithm to manipulate working days -

Problem: Find the date of nth working day from any particular day.

Solution:

1. Normalize to closest Monday -

   ```
   If today(or the initial day) happens to be something other than monday, bring the day to the closest monday by simple addition or subtraction.
   ```

   eg: Initial Day - 17, Oct. This happens to be wednesday. So normalize this no monday by going 2 dates down. 
       Now name this 2 dates, the initial normalization factor.
2. Add the number of working days + week ends that fall in these weeks.

   eg: to add 10 working days, we need to add 12 days. Since 10 days has 1 week that includes only 1 saturday and 1 sunday.
       this is because, we are normalizing to nearest monday.
3. Amortizing back -

   Now from the end date add the initial normalization factor (for negative initial normalization) and another constant factor (say, k).
   Or add 1 if the initial normalization is obtained from a Friday, which happens to be +3.
       If start date falls on Saturday and sunday , treat as monday. so no amortization required at this step.

   eg: Say if initial normalization is from wednesday, the intial normalization factor is -2. Hence add 2 to the end date and a constant k.

   ```
   The constant k is either 2 or 0.
   ```

Constant definition -

```
    If initial normalization factor is -3, then add 2 to the resulting date if the day before amortization is (wed,thu,fri) 
    If initial normalization factor is -2, then add 2 to the resulting date if the day before amortization is (thu,fri) 
    If initial normalization factor is -1, then add 2 to the resulting date if the day before amortization is (fri)
```

Example -

```
   Find the 15th working day from Oct,17 (wednesday).
```

Step 1 -

initial normalization = -2
   now start date is Oct,15 (monday).

Step 2 -

```
add 15 working days -

15 days => 2 weeks
    weekends = 2 (2 sat, 2 sun)

    so add 15 + 4 = 19 days to Oct, 15 monday.

    end_date = 2, nov, Friday
```

Step 3a -

```
end_date = end_date + initial normalization = 4, nov sunday
```

Step 3b -

```
end_date = end_date + constant_factor = 4, nov, sunday + 2 = 6, nov (Tuesday)
```

Cross Verfication -

```
 Add 15th working day to Oct, 17 wednesday

 Oct,17 + 3 (Oct 17,18,19) + 5 (Oct 22-26) + 5 (Oct 29 - Nov 2)  + 2 (Nov 5, Nov 6)

 Now the answer is 6, Nov, Tuesday.
```

I have verified with a few cases. Please share your suggesstions.

Larsen.

Comment: It seems like you've already solved your problem; good job!

Comment: To expand on @mfrankli's comment: Stack Overflow is a **question** and answer site. Where's your *question*?

Comment: The algorithm doesn't accounts for the holidays (non working days) that lie on days other than sat and sunday....for example christmas, easter etc

Comment: @Seasoned agree with you... but you have to maintain a separate holiday calender/catelog instead of going through such algorithms...

Comment: If we were to consider the business holidays, we would end up looping.
Then the algorithm would run in theta(n). But I wanted to have this at theta(1). And additionally, business days are country & company dependent, for which devising a generic logic would be tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider 0th working day from today (17/10, wed).

Step 1 -

```
 start_date = 17/10 wed
 normalized date = 15/10 mon
```

Step 2 -

end_date = normalized date + working days
            = 15/10 mon + 0 = 15/10 mon

Step 3 -

```
  amortized_back = end_date_before_amortization + normalization factor
                 = 15/10 + (+2) = 17/10 wed

  since the end_date_before_amortization falls on monday and initial normalization is 2, constant factor = 0.

  hence, end_date = 17/10 wed.
```

now case 2, 1st working day from today.

Step 1 -

```
 start_date = 17/10 wed
 normalized date = 15/10 mon
```

Step 2 -

end_date = normalized date + working days
            = 15/10 mon + 1 = 16/10 tue
Step 3 -

```
 amortized_back = end_date_before_amortization + normalization factor
                 = 16/10 + (+2) = 18/10 thu.

  since the end_date_before_amortization falls on tuesday and initial normalization is 2, constant factor = 0.

  hence, end_date = 18/10 thu.
```

Looks to be working for 0th and 1st WD.

Comment: In your soultion you have calculated 15 oct + 1 working days to be 16 oct, while in the original question you calculated 15 oct + 19 working days to be 2 nov, if 15+1 = 16 oct, then 15+19 working days should be 3rd nov and not 2nd nov.

Comment: Got it. In the first case the assumption was to include the current day as 1 working day. In the above solution I have missed to consider the current day as 1st working day. But I guess this discrepancy shouldn't affect logic on normalization and amortizing back. And this logic is not applicable for reverse calculation.

Comment: Good...yes, that minor assumption should not affect the alforithm in general. Well, once again, congartulations on writing this algo....all the best for future

Answer (score 5):

To start with, its a nice algorithm, i have doubts about boundary conditions though: for example, what if i need to find the 0th working day from today's date:

Step 1 -

```
initial normalization = -2 now start date is Oct,15 (monday).
```

Step 2 -

```
add 0 working days -

0 days => 0 weeks
    weekends = 0
    so add 0 + 0 = 0 days to Oct, 15 monday.

    end_date = 15, oct, monday
```

Step 3a -

```
end_date = end_date + initial normalization = 17, oct wednesday
```

Step 3b -

```
end_date = end_date + constant_factor = 17, Oct wednesday or 19,oct friday based on whether constant factor is 0 or 2 as it be only one of these values.
```

Now lets repeat the steps for finding the 1st working day from today:

Step 1 -

```
initial normalization = -2 now start date is Oct,15 (monday).
```

Step 2 -

```
add 1 working days -

1 days => 0 weeks
    weekends = 0
    so add 1 + 0 = 1 days to Oct, 15 monday.

    end_date = 15, oct, monday
```

Step 3a -

```
end_date = end_date + initial normalization = 17, oct wednesday
```

Step 3b -

```
end_date = end_date + constant_factor = 17, Oct wednesday or 19,oct friday based on whether constant factor is 0 or 2 as it be only one of these values.
```

Did you notice, algorithm gives the same end result for 0 and 1. May be thats not an issue if t defined beforehand that 0 working days and 1 working days are considered as same scenario, but ideally they should be giving different results.

I would also suggest you to consider the negative test cases, like what if i need to find -6th working day from today, will your alforithm give me a date in past rightfully?

Comment: constant factor should not be applied for the case considered with 0 working days because the end date before amortization comes to be Wednesday and initial normalization is 2.
V(Wednesday|Thursday|Friday,3) = 2
V(Thursday|Friday,2) = 2
V(Friday,1) = 2.
generically, V(day of week, initial normalization) = 2

Comment: I don't think we get the same answer for 0 WD and 1 WD.